# "Server connect failed" for skype 2.1 on Fedora 13

Tags: fedora, skype

All of a sudden I cannot login to Skype. I get "Server connect failed." I have the following in my .bashrc script:
alias skype='LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype'

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is an issue affecting several Skype customers in your position.  Apparently, the Skype servers are refusing communication with older versions of Skype for Fedora users.  Are you using the latests version of Skype?

http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-can-t-connect-in-Fedora/m-p/3451597